# × FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi i have this code i have using firebase v9 web. here is my code:

```
 const [post, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "posts"));

    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setPosts(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() }))
      );
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) has examples of both V8 name-spaced and V9 modular syntax:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, query, where, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore()

const q = query(collection(db, "posts"));

const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  setPosts(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() })))
});
```

Comment: i did this but now I have this error. src\Feed.js
  Line 20:16:  'snapshot' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @TheDevZak check updated answer.... it must be `querySnapshot.map()`

Comment: I changed to querySnapshot.map() but now i have ×
FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Comment: @TheDevZak pass the `db` ? Check updated answer.

Comment: @TheDevZak you still dont have `const db = getFirestore()` as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used to create the firebaseApp which I could use later on in the application. Since firebase@9 I got the same error. Now i create the firebaseApp before the database call which seems to work.

```js
const [post, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseOption);
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    const q = query(collection(db, "posts"));

    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setPosts(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() }))
      );
    });
  });
```